# Why function returns only one max value python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, max

I am trying to return the variable having the maximum value. But if the variable have the common values than the `max()` is returning only one value.   Her eis the what I got:

```
>>> d = {'x1':2,'x2':2}
>>> max(d, key=d.get)
'x2'
```

As one can see the values of both variables is `2`, the `max()` is returning the the output as one variable only and not both the larger values.

Kindly, let me know how `max()` can return multiple maximum values?

Comment: `max` can't return multiple values. If you want a function that does that, you'll have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There’s nothing built in for this, but you can use the same strategy that `max` does:

```
def max_all(iterable, *, key):
    it = iter(iterable)
    max_values = [next(it)]
    max_key = key(max_values[0])

    for x in it:
        x_key = key(x)

        if x_key > max_key:
            max_values = [x]
            max_key = x_key
        elif x_key == max_key:
            max_values.append(x)

    return max_values
```

[**demo**](https://ideone.com/KipHit)